# How to parse and retrieve line-delimited JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting a json file using a request `req.open("GET", ".../cgi-bin/data_file.json", true);` from my web server, the JSON file looks like this (separated by newline):

```
{"priority": "Low", "taskName": "Fry eggs", "userID": "Max", "description": "buy the eggs first "} 

{"priority": "Medium", "taskName": "buy car", "userID": "Jonathan", "description": " "}

{"priority": "Medium", "taskName": "Make dough", "userID": "Danielle", "description": " dough fresh"}`
```

when I parse it–`var jsonData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` How do I get each individual value for any key?

Comment: You can't `JSON.parse()` line-delimited JSON... you need to split lines first, best if done in a streaming manner.

Comment: not exactly, these are different result on separate lines, not just one @Sphinx

Comment: First, you would need to turn it into json. Until then, it isn't parsable.

Comment: Ideally, you'd fix whatever is creating the file such that it creates an array of objects.

Comment: No, currently it's multiple json strings, separated by new lines.

Comment: i'm reading data from a form, storing it in a dictionary and writing it into a json file. How would I create an array of objects? @KevinB

Comment: Add brackets, then separate with commas. `[{"priority": "Low", "taskName": "Fry eggs", "userID": "Max", "description": "buy the eggs first "} ,

{"priority": "Medium", "taskName": "buy car", "userID": "Jonathan", "description": " "},

{"priority": "Medium", "taskName": "Make dough", "userID": "Danielle", "description": " dough fresh"}]`

Comment: can't just add a bracket and separate with commas the way I'm writing to the file using python @KevinB

Comment: Sure you can. Any language can create valid json.